# combine 2 additional_settings fieldset

Tags: forms

I want to combine 2 fieldset that group in **additional_settings**.

I have 2 group added by some modules, I want combine them
one of it is
[image]

and another

[image]

I did combine 2 field, as author and path ... ( deafult field ) but here I have 2 fieldset.
how can  I merge them in one fieldset group?

I test this but they didnt combined correctly

`in form_alter`

```
    $circle=$form['user_relationship_circles_node_access'][1];
    unset($form['user_relationship_circles_node_access']);
    $circle['#group'] = '';
    $circle['#collapsible'] = FALSE;
    $circle['#element_validate'][] = 'MY_MODULE_path_form_element_validate';
    $circle['#element_validate'] = array_reverse($circle['#element_validate']);

    $form['user_relationship_node_access']['circle'] = $circle;
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this will be slightly different depending on exactly which 2 tabs you want to combine but in this example I will combine menu settings and url path settings like you mentioned in the question.

First you need to implement hook_form_alter:

```
function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

    switch($form_id) {

        case 'page_node_form':

            // dpm($form);

            $path = $form['path']; // assign the path part of the form to a variable
            unset($form['path']); // and unset the path section from the original form

            $path['#group'] = ''; // remove the group - if we keep this in then the fieldset won't sit inside the menu fieldset
            $path['#collapsible'] = FALSE; // and we no longer want our inner path fieldset to be collapsible

            // we need to add an additonal validation function to run before the one in the path module does to put the variables back where it is expecting them
            $path['#element_validate'][] = 'MY_MODULE_path_form_element_validate';
            // reverse the array to get our validation function to run first
            $path['#element_validate'] = array_reverse($path['#element_validate']);

            // and finally put the modifed path part of the form back, but put it inside the menu section
            $form['menu']['path'] = $path;

            break;

    }

}
```

And then to put the values back where the path module will be expecting them we need to add our custom validation function:

```
function MY_MODULE_path_form_element_validate($form, &$form_state, $complete_form) {

    // here we just need to take our values out of the menu section and put then back in the path section
    $form_state['values']['path'] = $form_state['values']['menu']['path'];

}
```

This will be a very similar process for any other tabs that you want to combine - use dmp to inspect the $form array and see what you need to take out and where you need to put it back. Then it is just a case of saving the node and seeing which errors appear. Then just put some code in place (such as the custom validation function) to fix any errors you have caused.

Comment: So ... do you have to be careful your module's weight makes it run _before_ the parent modules validation code is invoked?

Comment: Not the weight of the module, just the weight of that specific validation function. The modules weight is irrelevant in this specific example.

Comment: look at question again please

Comment: What exactly didn't work when you tried to combine them? Have you inspected your form array using dpm?

Comment: yes,I dsm $form, the work correctly in $form element array but in view I dont see them in one place,

Comment: What module are you using that created those tabs? Can you link to both of the modules project page that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

In core modules -> modules/node/content_types.inc file, i found something useful info but it is not worked out completely for me. I kept two arrays in one array. In the form settings, it is concatenating but not in proper way. Look below code which I merged "Submission settings" and "Display settings". May this trails little bit helps you.

```
  $form['display'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Display settings'),
    '#collapsible' => TRUE,
    '#collapsed' => TRUE,
    '#group' => 'additional_settings',
  );
  $form['display']['node_submitted'] = array( array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => t('Display author and date information.'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('node_submitted_' . $type->type, TRUE),
    '#description' => t('Author username and publish date will be displayed.'),
  ),
    array(
    '#title' => t('Title field label'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#default_value' => $type->title_label,
    '#required' => TRUE,
  ),
);

/*  $form['submission'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Submission form settings'),
    '#collapsible' => TRUE,
    '#group' => 'additional_settings',
  );
  $form['submission']['title_label'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Title field label'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#default_value' => $type->title_label,
    '#required' => TRUE,
  ); */
```